# Display Grafana values with unit without automatic change of metric prefix

Tags: grafana

I would like that grafana shows only the values in MB and not a mix of MB and GB. How can I force Grafana to use a single unit only?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using any unit that is built into Grafana (i.e. selectable in the *Unit* setting), it'll adjust automatically for large/small numbers with an appropriate metric prefix.

A workaround to have always the same unit displayed instead of the metric prefix automatically adjusted is to set it as *custom unit*. You can do it like that:

1. Go to the *Unit* selection.
2. Type your unit into the dropdown field, for example `XY`
3. Select the last option, that will be `Custom unit: XY`

This will also work for `MB`, **but only** if you select `Custom unit: MB`.

Comment: It works, but now my values have too many zeros at the end, the "Decimals" field I set to zero. Have grafana divide function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can divide your values already in your query for example. Maybe ask a seperate question and explain your issue there in more detail. If my answer solved your initial question, please consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: okay thank you very much! Grafana show me 60000000 mb instead of 600 mb

Comment: then you might want to devide the value by 1,000,000

Comment: How would one divide the value in this case?